# Access VBA Random line above button in Navigation Control

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

[image: See image here first]

First of all sorry for the minimal screenshot but I'm not able to show any data, however it should be enough for explanation reasons. 1, 2 and 3 are all buttons which make part of a navigation control form. In the image, button 2 is being pressed. They all open up their own form. For some odd reason it's been impossible to remove the orange line above button 1. And it has something to do with the pressed color since when i change the pressed color of button 1 to blue, the line obviously can't be seen. Any clue? been trying to fix this for a few hours but still can't manage. All buttons are the same size. Thanks.

Edit: Added new image of properties here [image: properties]

Comment: It seems to be a border property. Can you share some more  of your code/properties?

Comment: hi stefan, thanks for the reply, added an image of the properties above.

Comment: This is going to be a though one. Can you set all borders, all paddings and all gridlines to `transparent` and `0pt` in size? Oh, and make sure you backup your project first because *trail on error* can be a difficult thing to revert.

Comment: Just did, but everything remained the same. Oh and, added another button on the left of button 1, and now button one doesn't have a line on it. But the new one does. Weird. Starting to think this is a bug.

Comment: And it also has to do with when pressing the buttons. If I randomly press them, at one point the line appears above of one of the buttons.